# Creating Repository pattern for use with local .SQLite db in Swift

Tags: repository-pattern, swift5, sqlite.swift

I am building a SwiftUI app that pulls information from a local .SQLite database (using the SQLite.swift wrapper from https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md). I need to build a repository that sits between the View Service and the Database Manager. I am very new to repository pattern, and am struggling to find 1) documentation for using repository pattern in Swift 5, and 2) what exactly needs to be in the repository.
I found [this](https://pyartez.github.io/architecture/repository-pattern-in-swift-and-combine.html) example for using repository pattern in Swift, but it uses a web-based API for its code examples, and I can't find anything for use with a local db.
Code below is what I have in the repository so far:

```
struct doMaster: Codable {
    let doID: Int64
    let doName: String
    let doState: Bool
    let doCompletedState: Bool
    let doCategory: String
}

struct doDescription: Codable {
    let doID: Int64
    let doDescription: String
}

struct doStreaks: Codable {
    let doID: Int64
    let doStreak: Int64
}

struct doCategories: Codable {
    let category: String
    let categoryColor: String
}

class LocalRepository {
    let path: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first ?? ""
    let task = 
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You found “this”, that “this” link contains information about UserDefault. UserDefault is a local db provided by Apple.

Comment: @tail thanks for pointing that out! I did do a bit of digging into Apple's UserDefaults interface, but that db is for storing user preferences, as opposed to app data. UserDefaults was only mentioned once in the linked article, and there was no documentation in regard to how to use UserDefault with a repository.